# Groovy script stripping single quotes out of input

Tags: groovy

I have a need to convert log messages into JSON, so I decided to write a groovy script to try and accomplish the task. The log messages look like:

`InvoiceAdjustment{invoiceAdjustmentId=null, invoiceAdjustmentType='REFUND', invoiceId=20231189, currencyCode='USD', shippingRefundAmount=0.00, shippingRefundAmountUsd=0.00, taxTariffRefundAmount=0.00, taxTariffRefundAmountUsd=0.00, salesTaxTotalRefundAmount=0.00, salesTaxTotalRefundAmountUsd=0.00, vatRefundAmount=0.00, vatRefundAmountUsd=0.00, invoiceAdjustmentItems=[InvoiceAdjustmentItem{invoiceAdjustmentItemId=null, invoiceLineItemId=411729, refundAmount=3.82, refundAmountUsd=3.82, salesTaxRefundAmount=0.00, salesTaxRefundAmountUsd=0.00, returnQuantityExpected=0, returnQuantityActual=0, keptEnrolled=false, cancelShip=true, cancellationSuccessful=true, reshipQuantity=0, relativeLineNumber=4, sku='NTN-CHCK-339CV-NS163880', created=null, createdBy=null}], billingType='BRAINTREE', externalTransactionId='c3rvz7bv', refundTransactionId='null', reason='WAREHOUSE_CANCELLED', reshipmentInvoiceId=null, created=null, createdBy=null, refundedOn=null, notes='Cancelled by warehouse', createdByName='null', createdByEmail='null'}`

When iterating through these (using `String... args`) it appears all single quotes (which I want to key off to know if a field is a string) are gone! For example, the SKU field which is surrounded with single quotes in the input, prints as "`sku=NTN-CHCK-339CV-NS163880,`" -- no quotes!

Is there a way to keep the single quotes from the input so I can replace them in my script?

Here is the script in its entirety:

```
class LogToJson
{
    static void main( String... args )
    {
        if ( args.length == 0 )
        {
            println( "Error, you must provide a string." )
        }

        StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder()

        for ( String token : args )
        {
            if ( token.contains( "{" ) )
            {
                token = token.contains( "[" ) ? "\"" + token.substring( 0, token.indexOf( '[' ) - 1 ) + "\"=[{"
                        : "" +
                        "{\"" + token.substring( token.indexOf( "{" ) + 1, token.indexOf( "=" ) ) + "\"" + token.substring( token.indexOf( "=" ) )
            }
            else if ( token.contains( '=' ) )
            {
                token = "\"" + token.substring( 0, token.indexOf( '=' ) ) + "\"" + token.substring( token.indexOf( '=' ) )
            }
            token = token.replaceAll( '=', ':' ).replaceAll( "\'", "\"" )

            jsonBuilder.append( token + ' ' )
        }

        println( jsonBuilder.toString() )
    }
}
```

**Edited to add:** It appears if I escape all the single quotes in the input (i.e. replace `'` with `\'` before using it as input) the script works as expected. Ideally, I'd rather not have to do this.

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: @Seagull posted! The quotes should be replaced using `.replaceAll( "\'", "\"" )`

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit confused, and don't understand how it works and still can't reproduce a problem. Could it be, that single quotes are consumed by caller of your main method? Because if I just read this line from some file (or hardcoded string in my case), no quotes will be missing.

Comment: I'm calling this directly from the command line, i.e. `groovy LogToJson.groovy <the log message>`

Comment: I guess that's the culprit. Try Wrapping it with "" to pass it as a single string, and split in your script. `groovy LogToJson.groovy "…"`. Inside: `args[0].split(' ')`.
And I guess, if you need to process many lines, this can be very slow (as JVM is slow to start).